# Existstence of morphism into colimit

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathsf C$ be a cocomplete category.
If $\langle X_i,j_i\rangle$ is some inductive system in $\mathsf C$ and for each $i$ there is a morphism from some fixed $Y$ into $X_i$, then does there necessarily exist a morphism from $Y$ into the colimit $\varinjlim X_i$?

Answer (score 4):

Of course. Fix some $i$. Then there is a morphism from $X_i$ to the colimit (by definition of colimit), and since by assumption there is a morphism $Y\to X_i$ you get by composition a morphism from $Y$ to the colimit. Notice, that it suffices that there is a morphism from $Y$ to any one of the $X_i$, not all of them.